# .Net Core ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient set credentials

Tags: wcf, authentication, soap, reporting-services, asp.net-core

I am using ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient in .Net Core i got the latest version of .net Core and tried to get a report from reporting services to work. after I've used the WCF connection service I was able to add the code with looks like bellow

```
// Instantiate the Soap client
ReportExecutionServiceSoap rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient(ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.ReportExecutionServiceSoap);
// Create a network credential object with the appropriate username and password used
// to access the SSRS web service
string historyID = null;
TrustedUserHeader trustedUserHeader = new TrustedUserHeader();
ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

// Here we call the async LoadReport() method using the "await" keyword, which means any code below this method
// will not execute until the result from the LoadReportAsync task is returned

var taskLoadReport = rsExec.LoadReportAsync(reportPath, historyID);
// By the time the LoadReportAsync task is returned successfully, its "executionInfo" property
// would have already been populated. Now the remaining code in this main thread will resume executing

string deviceInfo = null;
string format = "EXCEL";
// Now, similar to the above task, we will call the RenderAsync() method and await its result
var taskRender = await rsExec.RenderAsync(renderReq);
```

When it hist renderAsync all falls apart because the credentials for the service are not set anywhere. I've  tried to Login async with no  success. Also I've tried to set the credentials with SetExecutionCredentialsAsync but I've got and error saying "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'." I don't know how to change that for ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient.

I have read some posts in which Microsoft guys says that the authentication with a soap is not resolved but for me it seems so close to be true. I feel like I am missing something.

Technology stack: VS 2017, .net Core web api, ssrs 2016, sql server 2016 standard

How can I authenticate the user for this call?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I am having similar issues to you and am finding it very difficult to find documentation anywhere.

Comment: @Radu: do you have full example of it? Appreciate the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I had the same issue and stumbled onto the answer.

After creating the ReportExecutionServiceSoap object you can specify the username and password in the ClientCredentials.  I've had success with this using the Basic client credential type.  Be sure you are using HTTPS, otherwise your password is sent in plaintext to the reporting server.  I also recommend storing the user/password in a secure place and not code.

```
BasicHttpBinding rsBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
rsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
rsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

EndpointAddress rsEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://servername/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx");

var rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient(rsBinding, rsEndpointAddress);
rsExec.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
rsExec.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
```

Comment: do you have full example of it? Appreciate the help